# Is iptables string matching still supported?

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables, netfilter

I was reading the book *Linux Firewalls - Attack Detection and Response* (by M. Rash, No Starch Press, 1 Ed., Oct. 2007). In one of its chapter it discusses string matching using `iptables`. I was wondering:

- if string matching is still supported by Linux kernel and
  iptables/Netfilter
- if yes, can string matching search the  encrypted payloads (e.g. HTTPS packets)?

I searched the net but most of the links are old, and the book itself is published in 2007.

Comment: I very much suspect that whatever it is you're doing, your iptables modules don't have the keys to any encrypted contents within the packets passing through them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [string extension](http://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.18) is still supported (see also your local `man iptables-extensions` documentation). No, you can’t match against encrypted payloads — they’re still encrypted in the filtering layer...

Comment: Thank you, Stephen would tell more about filtering layer?

Comment: By “filtering layer” I just meant the part of the kernel which handles packet filtering (`iptables` etc.).